# Can this distribution be sampled from efficiently? $f(x) \propto x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x - \gamma/x}$

Tags: distributions, sampling, simulation

Consider the density function

$$f(x|\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \propto x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x - \gamma/x}.$$

For $\alpha > 0$ and $\gamma = 0$, this clearly reduces to the Gamma distribution. For $\alpha < 0$ and $\beta = 0$, this reduces to the Inverse-Gamma distribution.

---

When $\alpha > 0$, $\beta > 0$ and $\gamma > 0$

1. Is there a name for this class of distributions?
2. Given $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, how can we efficiently sample from this distribution? I'm currently using an Accept-Reject scheme, but would like something more direct if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After quite a bit of searching - this is the density of a [Generalized Inverse Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution) random variable. There are a number of algorithms for sampling from this distribution.

R packages include [GIGrvg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GIGrvg/GIGrvg.pdf), [ghyp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ghyp/ghyp.pdf) and [Runuran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Runuran/Runuran.pdf). More details can be found in the following papers.

*Wolfgang Hörmann and Josef Leydold (2013). Generating generalized inverse Gaussian random variates, Statistics and Computing, DOI: 10.1007/s11222-013-9387-3*

*J. S. Dagpunar (1989). An easily implemented generalised inverse Gaussian generator, Comm. Statist. B – Simulation Comput. 18, 703–710.*

*Devroye, Luc. "Random variate generation for the generalized inverse Gaussian distribution." Statistics and Computing 24.2 (2014): 239-246.*

Answer (score 2):

scipy package in python can do it (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.geninvgauss.html#scipy.stats.geninvgauss), but its expression are slightly different from above. so I wonder how to convert their parameters